# Possible to move some selected row of a UITableView at the same time and order them?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is it possible to move items of uitablview and the same time when they were selected???
Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Question not clear?http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: on mac os ,we can drag more than one file which we selected.And then I just want to do this things using UITableView.This fuction allows user to drag or drop more than one uitableviewcell they selected.Any ideas?